# Crash When Opening Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I try to open a solution the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger opens stating;

> An unhandled Microsfot .NET Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe [3864].

Then provides me with Possible Debuggers the only on of which is 'New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'.

If I click no the whole thing closes, if I click yes it opens another Visual Studio with the title `devenv (Running)` for a few seconds then `devenv (Debugging)` which then crashes with;

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
InnerException:
```

After that my original solution just closes and I'm left with the empty devenv solution. Please help.

Comment: That's a very serious kind of exception, triggered when the internal state of the CLR gets corrupted.  You'll need to get your machine stable again.  A logical starting point is by disabling all add-ins or starting devenv.exe with the /safemode option to narrow down the cause.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms241278%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Hmm no clue why this worked but it did. I copied the solution folder to my desktop then took down an old copy from tfs without my changes. That ran fine. Recopied the changes from desktop over the tfs version and works fine now with my changes in place :/ Can't explain it, and don't really care so long as it's working! Thanks in any case Hans.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, some extensions require you to launch Visual Studio as an Administrator.  It seems like something small, but I ran it as admin and there it no longer crashed with the .net error.

Answer (score -1):

Go to configuration manager and select active solution platform-any cpu.